# Run Macros in Excel file from a SharePoint site

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have migrated some Excel files, which contain Macro, in SharePoint. I am trying to get the macro runs based on the files in Excel but I am getting the following error: "run-time error 76: Path not found".

When I have the files local, this code used to run perfectly:

```
    Sub Proceso_diarioLB()
'  PROCESO DIARIO MACRO
  Application.Run "'LIBRO MACROS LB.xlsm'!PROFLOSTN"
  Application.Run "'LIBRO MACROS LB.xlsm'!STOFCONDN"
  Application.Run "'LIBRO MACROS LB.xlsm'!COPIASTOFCONDN"
End Sub

Sub PROFLOSTN()
'
' PROFLOSTN Macro
'

'
    ChDir "S:\local\007repctrlbcocoa\DOWNLOADS\data"
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="S:\local\007repctrlbcocoa\DOWNLOADS\data\PL.txt"
```

How can I change the path so that it will pick the file in the SharePoint list.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The the file name and path in sharepoint are fixed, you need to update your VBA to use that path. Eg:  `Workbooks.Open "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1/TestLibrary/test.txt"`

Comment: FYI you do not need to use `Application.Run` if `Proceso_diarioLB` and `PROFLOSTN` are in the same workbook.

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations to using web based excel versus desktop versions, and one of them is that macros do not work via web based excel (eg. Opening within Sharepoint).

[See Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-excel-f0dc28ed-b85d-4e1d-be6d-5878005db3b6?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

> "A workbook in this format can be opened but macros do not run in a
> browser window."

Comment: Hi Purrple, thank you for your reply.
Does it work if they open the Excel file in the Desktop App?

Comment: If you open it locally on desktop Excel it should continue to work, but you may have to enable all macros in the trust center. In regards to multiple people opening the same file and having links, you will need to make sure that these are not "local" links and that they are accessible via a common drive. 

If this solves your issue please mark as accepted, but I'm happy to give further clarification if needed.

Comment: Thanks again Purrple. But I have never coded in Marco before so I don't know how to create a path to the SharePoint file. Is this something you can help me with?

Comment: You would need to swap your link with one that is not local - ie. one that is not solely on your computer. In theory, you can copy the link of your file from Sharepoint (select your file and hit "copy link") and try that, but I'll be honest, I haven't actually tried this myself within VBA so I'm not completely confident this will work. If on testing this doesn't work for you, you could save the files to a shared network drive and update the links within your VBA to reflect those locations (although I recognize this may not be ideal if you're using an online repository).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Linked files in Excel are not supported by Microsoft.
The reason for this is that files stored on sharepoint will create a link that is a web URL and not a normal file system location.
They will work like this but if anything (a change to your sharepoint structure or a necessary update to the folder structure within sharepoint) happens within sharepoint that causes the URL to change it will break these links. if you then try to delete and recreate these links (which is often difficult or impossible if you don't remember what file and tab and data was linked originally and didn't document it) as the URL stored by sharepoint isn't easily readable unlike a file location and excel also tends to throw errors when you try to re-create links saying there is already a link for that when you try to re-link.

Moral Microsoft don't support it for a reason, don't do it, if you need linked workbooks put them on a file share not Sharepoint and at most put a link to the file share location on sharpoint.